# how to put integer "range" in OWL literal value?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, literals, owl

Let's say that I have metal material in db that have property Yield strength which can go from 300 to 500 MPa. How can i enter that as literal value.

Should I put 2 properties like `YieldStrengthMin` and `YieldStrengthMax`, or it can be done in single entry and formatted something like 300 - 500. I know that I can put it like that as a string type, but what I need is that when I SPARQL my db, I should make query that will find all materials that have let's say `YieldStrength > 350`. If it's in that interval even partial it should be a valid result.

OK, another example to clarify

I will have db of materials and each type of material have many properties. Let's say `prop:hasMeltingTemperature`.

```
material:ZA-12 prop:hasMeltingTemperature    "380 - 430".

material:Zn    prop:hasMeltingTemperature    "420".
```

Some of them (clean materials) will have one melting temp, and temp of alloys will vary depending of percent of some components.

My application will have to get all materials from db that have let's say melting temperature > 400. So in this case it should get both of them.

And if I query that i need all materials that have melting temp < 425 it should take both of them too. If query is < 400, then only first material.

Anyway, my question is:

Should i make properties like this:

```
material:ZA-12 prop:hasMeltingTemperature_MIN "380".

material:ZA-12 prop:hasMeltingTemperature_MAX "430".

material:Zn    prop:hasMeltingTemperature     "420".
```

then when I query I have to detect ">" then compare it to "MIN" temp and "solo" temp, and if it's "<" then compare it to "MAX" temp and "solo" temp.

In this case I have to first detect does material have only "one" or "min-max" temp or "none" temp property.

OR

I can do it something like in the first example and have only one property like:

```
material:ZA-12 prop:hasMeltingTemperature "380 - 430".

material:Zn    prop:hasMeltingTemperature "420" .
```

and make some kind of sparql query that could understand "intervals" and compare them?

That's what I was wondering because there are many properties of materials, and many materials, and some of them have "min max" value, some "solo" value, and some don't have that property at all, but have another one with the same problem...

My application will be in php so i will have to generate sparql query in php, so that's why i was looking for some "universal" type of query (checking only one property)..

So my problem is more how to efficiently sparql query it, what's better choice of that 2 for storing data, and how to query it'

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking.  Are you asking: (a) how to state in the ontology that the value of some property must be between some values (e.g., `hasStrength 100` is OK, but `hasStrength 250` is not, because the _range_ of `hasStrength` is 100–200? (b) how to say that some _particular_ metal has a minimum strength of 100 and a maximum strength of 200? (c) how to _query_ for metals that have some particular strength?  All of these are easy enough to do, but we'll need clarification on what exactly you're trying to do before we can help.

Comment: just clarified it,i hope good enough

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I think the two property solution will work better for you.   I think that rather than using _three_ properties (e.g., `x1 hasMinVal y1 ; hasMaxVal y2. x2 hasExactVal y3`) you'll make your life simpler if you treat everything as a range, and instead of `hasExactVal`, do `x2 hasMinVal y3 ; hasMaxVal y3`  because then everything is consistent.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! :) will do that!

Comment: It's a **query** (not a *querry*) - one `r` is **quite enough!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a few different things that you could mean here.  You could

1. declare that the range of a property is a value within some range;
2. assert that for some particular individual, its values of a particular property are within some range;

Given that you said that:

> what i need is that when i SPARQL my db, i should make query that will
>   find all materials that have let's say YieldStrength > 350. If it's in
>   that interval even partial it should be a valid result.

### Using two properties

I think that your best best is to use two properties (e.g., `minStrength`/`maxStrength`).  This means that you can have data like:

```
metal72 minStrength 200 ;
        maxStrength 400 .
```

Then you can write a query with a pattern like

```
?metal minStrength ?min ;
       maxStrength ?max .
filter( ?min <= 350 && 350 <= ?max )
```

I think this most closely matches the idea you're trying to capture, because it sounds like each metal is actual associated with some *range* of values.  Where some metals can have exact values (and not a range), you can still use this approach, by putting in your data:

```
Zn minStrength 420 ;
   maxStrength 420 .
```

Then *all* of your metals are consistent (they *all* have a min value and a max value), and your queries won't have to worry about different cases.

### Using ranges, and querying the RDF serialization of the OWL

Now, while I think that the previous approach makes more sense, you *can* represent data ranges in OWL.  For instance, if there's a `hasStrength` property, you could say that some metal has strengths only within some range by using a restriction like

```
metal72 a (hasStrength only int[>=200,<=400])
```

In Protégé this looks like:

[image: restriction in Protege]

What this actually *means* though is not that the metal has some strength range, but that for any triple of the form `metal72 hasStrength x`, the value of `x` must be an `int` in the range `[200,400]`, or else the data is inconsistent.  This is obviously different than saying that the metal has a strength range.

The OWL ontology can be *serialized* in RDF, and then you can query the RDF using SPARQL.  You'll need to know what the RDF looks like though.  In this case, it's:

```
:metal72  a     owl:NamedIndividual , :Metal ;
        a       [ a                  owl:Restriction ;
                  owl:allValuesFrom  [ a                     rdfs:Datatype ;
                                       owl:onDatatype        xsd:int ;
                                       owl:withRestrictions  ( [ xsd:minInclusive
                                                         200 ] [ xsd:maxInclusive
                                                         400 ] )
                                     ] ;
                  owl:onProperty     :hasStrength
                ] .
```

That's a bit much, but you can query against it with SPARQL with a query like the following.  It will return any `?metal` which has a type `hasStrength only int[>=min,<=max]`, where `min ≤ 350 ≤ max`.

```
prefix metal: <http://www.example.org/metal#>
prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?metal where { 
  ?metal a metal:Metal ;
         a [ owl:allValuesFrom [ owl:withRestrictions [ rdf:rest* [ xsd:minInclusive ?min ] ] ;
                                                      [ rdf:rest* [ xsd:maxInclusive ?max ] ] ] ;
             owl:onProperty metal:hasStrength ] .
  filter( ?min <= 350 && 350 <= ?max ) 
}
```